# Why must the deviations from equilibrium be small for zero difference in energy in this solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, inductance

> A long solenoid with a square cross-section is partially immersed in a magnetic, non-conductive liquid of permeability $\mu$. The solenoid's axis is parallel to the liquid's surface.
>
> [image: diagram of square solenoid immersed in liquid]
>
> Task: determine what difference there will be between the liquid levels inside and outside the solenoid if there's a constant current $I$ flowing through the solenoid.

(57th Polish Olympiad in Physics, 2nd stage, 2008)

It is suggested that if the deviations from the equilibrium are small, then the difference of total energy should be $0$. Why? What would happen with the energy if the deviations weren't small?

Comment: What energy difference are you asking about? Between which two states?

Comment: The solution of the problem doesn't make this precise. It's one of the reasons why I have problems here. It's apparently the energy of the current supply, magnetic field and the gravitational energy, as far as I understand.

Comment: Obviously if you have so much current that the liquid level rises to the top of the solenoid, all bets are off - you can not get more potential energy once you're there but you can still increase the magnetic energy.

Comment: @marmistrz ah, good to know. If you wind up editing the question again, that might be good information to add in (though it may or may not be worth an edit on its own)